# API Connect 2018 VMware deployment: "host is missing traffic interface" error

Tags: ibm-cloud, esxi, apiconnect

I am trying to use InstallAssist (apicup) on ubuntu box to prepare the configuration file (apiconnect-up.yml) as part of creating an OVA file for management(mgmt) subsys.

I am having an issue with defining interfaces for the host (myhost.domain):

When I try **`apicup hosts list mgmt`** command, I get the following:

```
 apicmgt01.lab
    * host is missing traffic interface 
    * host is missing public interface 
    Device  IP/Mask                       Gateway
    eth0    192.168.10.166/255.255.255.0  192.168.10.1
```

The command I used to create the interfaces, based on [IBM KC](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_2018/com.ibm.apic.install.doc/overview_installing_mgmtvm_apimgmt.html?view=embed#overview_installing_mgmtvm_mgmt), is this:

```
picup iface create mgmt apicmgt01.lab eth0 192.168.10.166/255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1
```

I tried to google how exactly I need to set the those "traffic" and "public" interfaces with no success.

Note:

IBM knowledge reference mentions ***public_iface_id*** right after the command "**apicup iface create mgmt ...**" but it's not mentioned anywhere in the command itself nor anywhere else in the entire page!

With the scarce resource about the topic, I am struggling to get this part done. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just struggling with that, too.

If you run `apicup subsys get mgmt` you can see close to the output's beginning, there are values for public-iface and traffic-iface.

Make sure it's set to the correct value by running `apicup subsys set mgmt public-iface=<iface_name>` and `apicup subsys set mgmt traffic-iface=<iface_name>`.